# wordcloud package install error

Tags: r

I tried to install `wordcloud` package in R 
but it seems can not be installed , and return the error as below.
Could someone tell me how to fix it or download from some other source?

```
install.packages("C:/Users/Owner/Desktop/wordcloud_2.5.tar.gz", repos = NULL, type = "source")
Installing package into ‘C:/Users/Owner/Documents/R/win-library/3.2’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
ERROR: dependency 'slam' is not available for package 'wordcloud'
* removing 'C:/Users/Owner/Documents/R/win-library/3.2/wordcloud'
Warning in install.packages :
  running command '"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-32~1.2/bin/x64/R" CMD INSTALL -l "C:\Users\Owner\Documents\R\win-library\3.2" "C:/Users/Owner/Desktop/wordcloud_2.5.tar.gz"' had status 1
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘C:/Users/Owner/Desktop/wordcloud_2.5.tar.gz’ had non-zero exit status
```

Comment: `install.packages('slam')`

Comment: > install.packages('slam')
Installing package into ‘C:/Users/Owner/Documents/R/win-library/3.2’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
Package which is only available in source form, and may need compilation of
  C/C++/Fortran: ‘slam’
  These will not be installed

Comment: i still get error from this

Comment: You probably also need Rtools: https://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/Rtools/

Comment: If you got this to work you should post it as a solution and mark it correct.

Answer (score 1):

To do this basically you will need these steps, probably the best way

> 1. install.packages("slam")    --while doing this it will ask you to select a country which you will have to do and within few minutes it
>      will all be done.
> 2. install.packages("wordcloud") -- this will also be installed and built.

then just type

```
  >library(wordcloud)
  Loading required package: RColorBrewer
  Warning message:
  package ‘wordcloud’ was built under R version 3.4.2
```